# subscription in RapidAPI.com

Tags: subscription, rapidapi

Does buying a plan in RapidAPI allow access and request for all the APIs on this site? For example, if we buy a Mashvisor pro plan, will we have access to Realty Mole Property and send request to get its data?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to Subscribe to a particular API each time you want to use it. If you buy a [Mashvisor API](https://rapidapi.com/mashvisor-team/api/mashvisor/pricing) plan, you can only test and connect to Mashvisor API.

Moreover, RapidAPI is a huge API hub where you can find, connect and test more than 35K public APIs. There is a plethora of free APIs as well, which doesn't even require your card details. This way, you don't need to buy a plan to use a particular API on RapidAPI Hub.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.